# How to update multiple rows in PostgresDB with NOW()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to update multiple rows in the table on the PostgreSQL Database.
I tried to update the `date` column to the current time by using this SQL command, however, it did not work.

```
UPDATE data as d SET
    date = c.date
FROM (values
    ('data_id_1', NOW()),
    ('data_id_2', NOW())
) as c(data_id, date)
where c.data_id = c.date;
```

I got this error message when I run this SQL command on the console.

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: text = timestamp with time zone
```

I am not sure where the is wrong. I would appreciate any advice or suggestions! Thank you very much.

Comment: PostgreSQL can compare date and timestamp (with or without time zone) automatically. If one is a date it is cast to timestamp automatically (0:0 hours).

The error message tells a different story. You are actually trying to input a date with invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you intend something like this:

```
update data d
    set date = c.date
from (values ('data_id_1', NOW()),
             ('data_id_2', NOW())
     ) c(data_id, date)
where c.data_id = d.data_id;
```

That is, the `join` condition should be *between* the tables rather than just on `c`.

This logic would more typically be written as:

```
update data d
    set date = now()
where d.data_id in ('data_id_1', 'data_id_2')
```